# Creating a custom Image gallery that looks like Safari's "Show Top Sites" in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, image, safari, gallery

I am trying to create a view which shows similar the way of Safari's "Show Top Sites" option. I have bunch of images to be displayed in that gallery view. Any idea or suggestion to create this in my cocoa application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into [Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartz/quartzcomposer.html). Here's the [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_intro/qc_intro.html). A composition would do most of the heavy lifting, getting the images from your application. It's a broad topic, so a specific answer would be more like a longish tutorial. It might be best to break this question down into smaller ones once you're familiar with Quartz Composer.

There are a few [communities](http://www.quartzcompositions.com/phpBB2/) out there that focus on the topic as well.

Comment: thanks but is there any way using NSViews . If we have a grid view how can we give that effect to the gridview?.